# DrawerLayout taking full screen width and not able to slide

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, androidx

Im using `androidx` and new `"com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"` but `DrawerLayout` is not working properly. It takes full screen width and Im not even able to slide it. Check attachment [image]

Below is my simple layout:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.DrawerActtivity"

    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_item_selection"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_item_selection"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"

        />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I check my other project and its same with `support` libraries. i think issues is with these new material libs

Comment: You're missing the `layout_gravity` attribute on the `<NavigationView>`.

Comment: Damn, literally sometimes we miss minor things... Thank you @MikeM.

Comment: No problem. Happens to us all. Cheers!